# How to load plugin modules in Angular 4

Tags: angular, design-patterns, loading

I'm developing a dashboard in angular 4 which will allow other developers to create plugins for displaying various data. The dashboard has some common elements such a navigation bar that will show all available plugins. Here is where my problem comes. I would like the developers to register their plugins into the dashboard without having to modify the dashboard's source code. This brings two issues to me:

1. How the dashboard can discover these plugins? Ideally, I would like to instantiate them as singletons at bootstrap time, and let them "announce" themselves using some form of plugin registry service. I actually created this service, but haven't been able to create the plugin instances. I've seen there are workaround's to dynamically load components from a source folder, but they all look as hacks and very fragile.
2. How to register the plugin routing routes.

Any advice on which design pattern would be greatly appreciated.